# Html: For Select multiple, only one value is submitted but .val() returns array of two values

Tags: php, jquery, html, form-submit, multiple-select

When rendering the page, the `val()` of a multiple select is set with a single value. For example, `$("#my_select_box").val(1);` 
Then the user selects an additional value in the multiple select box.

When the form is submitted, only the newly selected value is submitted and not the previously set one. Whereas while debugging in Firefox, the `.val()` function returns an array of two values (both the previous one and the newly selected one). Why does this happen?

Answer (score 36):

If you are programming in PHP, the problem lies there. When using multiselect inputs, PHP requires you to have an empty pair of brackets after input name. For example:

```
<select name="select[]" multiple="multiple">
```

rather than just

```
<select name="select" multiple="multiple">
```

If you can't or won't do this (perhaps you don't have access to the underlying HTML), then you can alternatively capture the POST data like this:

```
$data_from_post = file_get_contents("php://input");
var_dump($data_from_post);
```

And you'll see a string like this that you can use:

```
select=one&select=two&select=three&button=submit
```

Comment: If you want to convert that last string into a workable array, `parse_str()` will not work, as it will throw out the duplicate elements. There is a simple function named `proper_parse_str()` that will work, available at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792

Answer (score 3):

Well, without code we can't be sure. But when you want multiple params to be passed in you have to give a name value of that input the [ ] brackets. Ex. "name[]" so in order for the server to know that there are in fact two values.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what to do without the code.

However, if you want both the `option` that you marked `selected` and another that was selected, you could access them as follows:

`option[selected="selected"]` for the one you set

and

`option:selected` for the one chosen by the user

So something like this...

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var s = $('#my_select_box option[selected="selected"]').val(); 
    var t = $('#my_select_box option:selected').val();
    alert("Set: " + s + ", Chosen: " + t);
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/pZesG/1/